# Fill column rows with incremented value after index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a numeric column a) and I need to create a new one that is 0 when a) is > 100 and then increment 1 for the rows below and -1 for the rows above.

For example

```
a  b

0 -5
20 -4
40 -3
60 -2
80 -1
100 0
120 1
140 2
160 3
```

I managed to fill the rows with 0s after 100 but now I am struggling to increment below and above that index.

`df_confirmed_portugal['day_100'] = df_confirmed_portugal.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['Confirmed'] > 100 else -1, axis=1 )`

Can I get some help on how to do this?

Kind Regards

Comment: Just to confirm: you have exactly one `100` in your data?

Comment: No, I don't even have one 100, after a certain row it goes higher than 100, which is my 0-value

Comment: Then go for @a_guest's answer, change `df['a']==100` to `df['a']>=100`.

Comment: Yes, that answer looked really neat. Just a little issue with that. 
Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract the position of the first element greater than or equal to `100` from a `np.arange` sequence:

```
df['b'] = np.arange(len(df)) - np.argmax(df['a'] >= 100)
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that mention that the index are not sequential because this df is a result from a filter. But I do like your suggestion. Is there any way that I can reset my index to become 0 to len(df)?

Comment: @LuísCosta I don't understand what you mean, Could you update your question with an example?